# PHP PDO - How Can I Do This

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need a way to either do 4 queries or do make my `$views` variable be able to like switch from grabbing the highest view count to the 2nd highest view count etc and I need them to be formatted like an array so `$views[0];` is the 1st highest view count and `$views[4];` is the 4th highest count.

Code:

```
//Load Database Details
    require_once 'functions/db/dbconfig.php';

    //Database Connect - View - High - 1
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    //Query and Fetch
    $res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tvinfo ORDER BY views LIMIT 0, 1;");
    $res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res->execute();
    $Result = $res->fetchAll();

    //Result Variables
    foreach ($Result as $r) {
        $name = $r['name'];
        $rating = $r['rating'];
        $imdbid = $r['imdbid'];
        $genre1 = $r['genre1'];
        if(!empty($r['genre2'])){ $genre2 = '- '.$r['genre2']; }
        $year = $r['year'];
        $views = $r['views'];
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking but perhaps you want `ORDER BY views DESC` ?

Comment: It will give the results in a descending order. In your case the row with the highest views would be on top, then second highest after that and so on.

Comment: In that case thats partially what I want then I guess, but how would I make a $view variable for each one so that I could output $views[0] would output whatever is the highest views count in the database and $views[3] would be the 4th highest views count.

Comment: Perhaps a new array would be the way to go. Give me a minute I will formulate an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but should work.

```
require_once 'functions/db/dbconfig.php';

//Database Connect - View - High - 1
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

//Query and Fetch
$res = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tvinfo ORDER BY views DESC LIMIT 4;");
$res->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$res->execute();
$Result = $res->fetchAll();
//Result Variables
$views = array();
foreach ($Result as $r)
{
    $name = $r['name'];
    $rating = $r['rating'];
    $imdbid = $r['imdbid'];
    $genre1 = $r['genre1'];
    if(!empty($r['genre2'])){ $genre2 = '- '.$r['genre2']; }
    $year = $r['year'];
    $views[] = $r['views'];
}

var_dump($views);
```

Comment: That works fine, but how can I limit it to only outputting 4 view counts into the array like what LIMIT do I use not sure what the 0, 1 means.